# map[string]string inside a struct

Tags: go

Apologies for the title, but this is a weird one and out of my ability to understand.

I'm working with a go library that's sort of finished, but sort of not:

https://github.com/yfronto/go-statuspage-api

The statuspage.io API supports the following params when posting an incident:

```
incident[components][component_id] - Map of status changes to apply to affected components.
```

An example would be:

```
"incident[components][ftgks51sfs2d]=degraded_performance"
```

Unfortunately, the struct defined in the library [doesn't support that particular field](https://github.com/yfronto/go-statuspage-api/blob/master/incident.go#L116-L134):

```
type NewIncidentUpdate struct {
    Name               string
    Status             string
    Message            string
    WantsTwitterUpdate bool
    ImpactOverride     string
    ComponentIDs       []string
}

func (i *NewIncidentUpdate) String() string {
    return encodeParams(map[string]interface{}{
        "incident[name]":                 i.Name,
        "incident[status]":               i.Status,
        "incident[message]":              i.Message,
        "incident[wants_twitter_update]": i.WantsTwitterUpdate,
        "incident[impact_override]":      i.ImpactOverride,
        "incident[component_ids]":        i.ComponentIDs,
    })
}
```

How can I update this struct (and [the associated encodeParams function](https://github.com/yfronto/go-statuspage-api/blob/master/http_helper.go#L69-L112)) to support passing an arbitrary map of components and associated statuses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could embed a `NewIncidentUpdate` inside your own struct that defines the component status changes.

```
type MyIncidentUpdate struct {
    NewIncidentUpdate
    ComponentStatusChanges map[string]string
}
```

then define `String` the same way, while accomodating for your `ComponentStatusChanges` map.

```
func (i *MyIncidentUpdate) String() string {
    params := map[string]interface{}{
        "incident[name]":                 i.Name,
        "incident[status]":               i.Status,
        "incident[message]":              i.Message,
        "incident[wants_twitter_update]": i.WantsTwitterUpdate,
        "incident[impact_override]":      i.ImpactOverride,
        "incident[component_ids]":        i.ComponentIDs,
    }
    for k, val := range i.ComponentStatusChanges {
        key := fmt.Sprintf("incident[components][%s]", k)
        params[key] = val
    }

    return encodeParams(params)
}
```

Comment: This is assuming I didn't want to modify the existing library, but I'm quite happy to fork the repo and update the repo in place, is there a way to do that?

Comment: @jaxxstorm if they accept your PR, then sure. Simply change their `NewIncidentUpdate` to include the status changes map and update the `String` method (and any other method that might be affected -- I haven't scoured the repo) accordingly. (and good on you for contributing to existing projects!)

Comment: Thanks for the fantastic answer, really appreciated!